# P6spy doesn't spy on hsql jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb, p6spy

When trying to spy on the jdbc connection to a hsqldb database it doesn't work.
It looks like the org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver is not deregistered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to deregister both drivers registered by hsqldb.jar.

In spy.properties you should have

```
realdriver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
realdriver2=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
deregisterdrivers=true
```